# SQL Server - how can this query be optimized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, query-optimization

This query is taking an average of 4 seconds.  It will become a subquery in a stored procedure and I need it to take a sub second.  Here is the query:

```
(select customercampaignname + ' $' + convert(varchar, cast(amount as numeric(36,2) ) ) As 'Check_Stub_Comment2' from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY amount desc) as rownumber, customercampaignname, amount from (
        select * from (
               select distinct d.customercampaignname
                   ,sum(d.mastercurrencyamount) As amount

                from bb02_donation d
                      JOIN bb02_donationline dl on d.donationid = dl.donationid
                      JOIN bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs on dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid and frs.fundraiserid = 1869

                where d.customercampaignname is not null 
                      and d.customercampaignname != '' 
                group by d.CustomerCampaignName
        ) as x
) as sub ) as y where rownumber = 1)
```

Comment: To clarify - "where rownumber = " is important.  I need to be able to select only row 1, or row 2 exclusively.

Comment: The answer I marked below does make this query faster, however it's still n+ calls to the database.  In my case I am only concerned with 2 results so I stored them into a temp table with just one call to the database.  Then I was able to take the top 1 result, sort it, and take the top 1 result again, from the temp table.  This cut my total query time in half.  Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to actually use the row number for anything, then I would just go with getting the TOP 1 row. The query could be simplified a lot. I like to start by first selecting from the table that will be filtered out the most by your predicates. Hopefully, you have a good index on frs.fundraiserid and all of the columns participating in the joins.

```
SELECT 
 TOP 2 customercampaignname + ' $' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), CAST(SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) AS NUMERIC(36,2) ) ) AS 'Check_Stub_Comment2',
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC) as rownumber
FROM bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs
JOIN bb02_donationline dl ON
 dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid
JOIN bb02_donation d ON
 d.donationid = dl.donationid          
WHERE frs.fundraiserid = 1869
 AND d.customercampaignname IS NOT NULL
 AND d.customercampaignname != '' 
GROUP BY d.CustomerCampaignName
ORDER BY SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC
```

Since you need to be able to select either the 1st or 2nd row, then wrap it up in a CTE or subquery.

```
WITH topcampaign AS (
SELECT 
 TOP 2 customercampaignname + ' $' + CONVERT(varchar(255), CAST(SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) AS NUMERIC(36,2) ) ) AS 'Check_Stub_Comment2',
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC) as rownumber
FROM bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs
JOIN bb02_donationline dl ON
 dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid
JOIN bb02_donation d ON
 d.donationid = dl.donationid          
WHERE frs.fundraiserid = 1869
 AND d.customercampaignname IS NOT NULL
 AND d.customercampaignname != '' 
GROUP BY d.CustomerCampaignName
ORDER BY SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC
)
SELECT * from topcampaign WHERE rownumber = 1
```

As another possible optimization, I took the CONVERT out of the CTE and put it in the final select. Not sure if that helps much.

```
WITH topcampaign AS (
SELECT 
 TOP 2 
 customercampaignname,
 SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) AS amount,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC) as rownumber
FROM bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs
JOIN bb02_donationline dl ON
 dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid
JOIN bb02_donation d ON
 d.donationid = dl.donationid          
WHERE frs.fundraiserid = 1869
 AND d.customercampaignname IS NOT NULL
 AND d.customercampaignname != '' 
GROUP BY 
 d.CustomerCampaignName
ORDER BY 
 SUM(d.mastercurrencyamount) DESC
)
SELECT 
 rownumber,
 customercampaignname + ' $' + CONVERT(varchar(255), CAST(amount AS NUMERIC(36,2) ) ) AS 'Check_Stub_Comment2'
FROM topcampaign 
WHERE rownumber = 1
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually need the row number so that I can select either the 1st or 2nd row.  Top 1 would work, but I still would need a way to query for the 2nd row.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the ROW_NUMBER to the output. You can change TOP to be TOP N Where N is any valid integer. So if you need only the top 2 and also need the rownumber, then change it to TOP 2.

Comment: Let me explain again.  I need it to either return row 1 OR return row 2 exclusively.  So, I would need to say "where rownumber = 2" and get only row 2 in the result set.  I'm trying to make that happen with your sql above right now.

Comment: I was able to wrap your sql above with select * from (-your sql') as x where rownumber = 2

Comment: that ran in under 1 second so it looks promising so far.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the requirement of selecting either the 1st or 2nd row. I always preferred CTE rather than subqueries because it's clearer to me, but that's just me.

Comment: Did this end up being fast enough?

Comment: It definitely sped things up, but it wasn't fast enough.  I don't think it could get much faster so I had to take a different route.  I put the results (top 2 rows) into a temp table, then to get each result I would first take the top 1, then sort it, then take the top 1 again.  Basically this gave me the larger amount on top, then after the sort gave me the lower amount.  Hard to explain here.  I'm marking your answer as correct since it works, but it turns out the entire question just was going down the wrong road for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will run faster, but by my reckoning, this can be simplified to:

```
Select top 1 customercampaignname + ' $' + convert(varchar(255), cast(sum(d.mastercurrencyamount) as numeric(36,2) ) ) As amount
from bb02_donation d JOIN
     bb02_donationline dl
     on d.donationid = dl.donationid JOIN
     bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs
     on dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid and frs.fundraiserid = 1869
where d.customercampaignname is not null and d.customercampaignname != '' 
group by d.CustomerCampaignName
order by sum(d.mastercurrencyamount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this makes any difference

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY amount desc) as rownumber
    from (
        select distinct d.customercampaignname, sum(d.mastercurrencyamount) As amount
        from bb02_donation d
        INNER JOIN bb02_donationline dl on d.donationid = dl.donationid
        INNER JOIN bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream frs on dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid and frs.fundraiserid = 1869
        where d.customercampaignname is not null 
                and d.customercampaignname != '' 
        group by d.CustomerCampaignName
    ) as x
)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM cte 
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

if the tables are quite you might need to help filtering out things, for example, you could pick only bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream.fundraiserid = 1869 and then do the rest of the query. 
I don't know, it could be a matter of trying and see the execution plan.

```
;WITH Frs AS 
( SELECT dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid 
  FROM bb02_fundraiserrevenuestream
  WHERE fundraiserid = 1869
)
, cte AS (
    select d.customercampaignname, sum(d.mastercurrencyamount) As amount
    from Frs
    INNER JOIN bb02_donationline dl  ON dl.fundraiserrevenuestreamid = frs.fundraiserrevenuestreamid
    INNER JOIN bb02_donation d on d.donationid = dl.donationid
    where d.customercampaignname is not null 
            and d.customercampaignname != '' 
    group by d.CustomerCampaignName
)
SELECT TOP 1  customercampaignname + ' $' + convert(varchar, cast(amount as numeric(36,2) ) ) As 'Check_Stub_Comment2' 
FROM cte
ORDER BY sum(d.mastercurrencyamount)
```

As always, `INDEXES` could be the solution for these performance problems.